# PHP - how to link other pages in view in ci

Tags: php, html, css

I am new to CodeIgniter. I am using a bootstrap template. welcome_page.php is my view file. I have tried to link my home button to redirect to another page that is '***dashboard.php***' which is in view folder of my project. I am getting an error "*_the access is forbidden_ or _object is not found_*".
Can anyone tell me how to link pages with an example. Thanks for the help.

**controller file code:**

```
 public function home() 
     {
         $this->load->view('dashboard');
     }
```

**view file code:**

```
<li class="nav-item active">
 <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo BASE_PATH . "views/dashboard.php";?>">Home
    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
 </a>
 </li>
```

Comment: Though I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter, there should be template functions to help you do this, you shouldn't need to use a path linking directly to your views folder. Something in these docs might be what you need: [https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Comment: What is the URL when you get that error? Does it match the URL that you expect?

Comment: "http://localhost/blog_ci/views/dashboard.php" this is the URL  when I get an error @PatrickQ blog_ci is my project folder and dashboard.php is my view file.

Comment: @hungerstar thank you i am trying :)

Comment: @dharasd I'm also not really familiar with CI, but from the other frameworks that I _have_ used, it seems odd that you would be navigating directly to a view. Generally you navigate to a controller and action, which then runs/loads the view.

Comment: @PatrickQ     can you tell me how to link with a controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entry point for any MVC framework is the controller and you cannot access views directly.

In CodeIgniter, the url is composed of controller name and action name (public method in controller).
For example if you want the url
`localhost/index.php/welcome/dashboard`. You need to have a controller class called `Welcome` and a public method in that controller called `dashboard`. You can display the view by putting the command `$this->load->view('welcome_message');` in function `dashboard`.
Url format:

`<Your project root>/index.php/<small caps of the controller name>/<name of the public function in the controller>`

All of this means that you just need to add function `dashboard` to your controller named `Welcome`.
Your controller should look like this.

```
public function home() 
     {
         $this->load->view('dashboard');
     }

public function dashboard() 
     {
         $this->load->view('welcome_page');
     }
```

Now you can access url `localhost/index.php/welcome/dashboard`

You can read more in their tutorial
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html#static-pages

Comment: thank you, sir, very much now I am able to load my view. i need one more help the view which I am loading through URL. I want that when I click on a home button then it will redirect me to that view page. how can i link that page to home button ?

Comment: Make sure you have set `$config['base_url']` in `config/config.php`. In your view, load helper `$this->load->helper('url');` and add your href as `<?=base_url().'index.php/welcome/dashboard'?>`